# Is it safe to use thread that manipulate the current object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Imagine I have the following:

```
struct A {

     std::vector<int> _vect;
     std::mutex _mutex;

     void f () {
         std::thread t1(&A::work, this);
         std::thread t2(&A::work, this);
         t1.join();
         t2.join();
     }

     void work () {
         std::vector<int> cvect;
         while (true) {
             bool keep = false;
             _mutex.lock();
             // get_next() modify the internal state of this
             keep = get_next();
             cvect = _vect; // copy of _vect
             _mutex.unlock();
             if (!keep) break;
             // Do some stuff that does not require the `this`, e.g.:
             std::sort(cvect.begin(), cvect.end());
             int v = cvect.back() - cvect.front();
         }
     }

     bool get_next () {
         // This methods modify _vect
         _vect = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}; // e.g.
     }
}

int main () {
    A a;
    a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

The above compiles, and works (with a more complicated implementation).

1. Is it safe (if not, how can I make it safe?)?
2. What wrong may happen during `_work` (which cases are not correctly handled?)?

Comment: `A` object is living while threads `t1` and `t2` are executed. So, why do you think your code is unsafe?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't think it is, but since I had never manipulated `thread` and `mutex` before, I thought I may have forgotten something...

Comment: "does not require the this pointer" means no member variable is accessed?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon Yes, I have updated the post. Typically, I update the internal state of `this` during the lock, make a copy of a member variable (still during the locak), and then work on the copy (calling external function).

Comment: Yes it is safe ("Don't panic")

Comment: It seems suspicious that you spawn threads only to lock as soon as you enter `work()`, thereby serializing the call. It may be that the serialization lasts very little and that the `// Do some stuff that does not require the 'this' pointer` part actually benefits from threading, but --- again--- it seems suspicious at first glance.

Comment: @Escualo Typically, I am trying to find an optimum to a problem: the part that does require the `this` keyword generate possible solutions (pretty fast) and then the worker solve a problem (pretty slow) to find the objective value for the current solution. The idea is to have multiple workers computing objective but using the same "pool" of solutions (so each solution is only check once).

Comment: @Holt Then it seems that you probably don't need locks: create a method (or, even better, an stand-alone function that receives an instance of `A`) that generates (serially, no locks involved) all the possible solutions. Then spawn the threads to run the optimization.

Comment: @Escualo It could be possible depending on the size of the solution space you're right, but I would still have to use lock to update the best solution I guess?

Comment: @Holt not necessarily, because every thread could return its best solution (serially, to a container), and you get the "best of the best" in one shot at the end.

Comment: @Escualo I see. Thanks for the leads, I will check if I can implement it the way you propose when I get back to the code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current implementation has a subtle bug. I wonder if you have it in your real code as well.

```
 while (true) {
       _mutex.lock();
       // get_next() modify the internal state of this
      if (!get_next()) break;
       _mutex.unlock();
```

Here the break will exit the loop and leave the mutex locked. Welcome to deadlock! To fix that subtle problem, I really suggest avoiding using `mutex.lock()`/`unlock()`. Instead one should use `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock`.

Comment: I don't have it in my real code (updated the question manually without checking... ). I did not know about `lock_guard` and `unique_lock`, I will check them, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

the rules are as follows:

1. Reading and writing to the same variable from different threads is undefined behaviour.
2. Reading and writing to the same variable *not* at the same time without any locking or atomic actions may lead to memory invisibility. one thread may not "read" the latest value written by the other thread
3. Reading the same variable from two different threads is thread safe.

To your questions:

> // Do some stuff that requires the `this` pointer.

if the "stuff" is only reading from members pointed by `this` than the whole locking is redundant. 
one the other hand, if one thread changes `this` in some sort than the locking is mandatory. in this case the locks makes the concurrent actions thread-safe

> // Do some stuff that does not require the `this` pointer.

yet again, if the only action taken in both of the threads is reading, than the method is thread safe. if one thread is writing to the variable (**regardless if it is a member variable or not! the thread sees only memory addresses**) and the other is reading/writing to it, than you must either lock that variable or use atomics for it.

> What wrong may happen during _work (which cases are not correctly
>   handled?)?

On the land of undefined behaviour anything may happen. what happens,for example, when you dereference invalid memory address?

PS. use standard RAII wrappers to lock the mutex, do not lock it manually yourself.